# CSS for centered, automatic width div elements, one per line

Tags: css

There seems to a plethora of CSS questions available to search, but I haven't managed to find anything that answers my question and none of the solutions happen to do the trick either.

I'd like to have a bunch of divs, one per line, that is centered inside a parent container, and have an automatic width based on their text contents.

The automatic width part I have managed with display: inline-block, but then I end up with the divs next to eachother (as many as can fit inside the parent container).

Any help? Thanks!

EDIT: Also, I have considered going the Table route, would this be the right thing to do (I.e. a table with a single column with multiple rows)

EDIT: An example always makes things clearer...

I have a column with a series of divs:

```
<div id="giant-column" style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div class="column-element" style="margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;">
    <div class="text" style="width: 100%; clear: both;"> ... </div>
    <div class="author" style="float: right;"> ... </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

I would like each "column-element" to be only as wide as "text", but centered within the bigger column "giant-column". Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

```
div.column-element{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I omitted that from the example but I have it in my CSS

Comment: are you sure your .column-element's are only the text width? Have you tried to add them borders to see it visually?

Comment: If you add display: inline-block, yes.

Comment: Right. The only reason I'm using inline-block is to scale the width to the text. Perhaps there is a better way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
margin:0 auto;
```

at your inner divs?

Table design isn't so agile so we don't consider it to be a good solution. There are so many different options with tableless design.

Comment: I have tried margin: 0 auto; the question is really "where?" :) Perhaps I should illuminate with an example...

Comment: "Table desing isn't so agile" - Huh? It's not a good solution because **it's not semantic**.

Comment: Don't you need to define a width to use this auto margin centering technic?

Answer (score 0):

Ha! Figured it out... I needed another div element that wraps each line with width: 100%;

```
<div id="giant-column" style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="column-element" style="margin: 0 auto; display: inline-block;">
    <div class="text" style="width: 100%; clear: both;"> ... </div>
    <div class="author" style="float: right;"> ... </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: `width: 100%;` is the default of course, so you're just forcing each column element on to its own line. You could have done that with line breaks (`<br>`) for instance.

Comment: Ah, so I can actually omit the width and just have the div element.

Comment: Actually, `width: auto;` is the default, but when the margin is also auto (which is also the default) then it's as if the width is 100%.